# Disable All Touch Screen Interactions While Animation

Tags: android, android-widget, clickable

I wish to disable all the touch screen interactions while an animation is being displayed.
I don't wish to use the `setClickable()` method on the buttons at the start or end of the animation because there are a large number of buttons. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

In your Activity, you can override `onTouchEvent` and always `return true;` to indicate you are handling the touch events.

You can find the documentation for that function [there](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29).

**Edit** Here is one way you can disable touch over the whole screen instead of handling every view one by one... First change your current layout like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    < .... put your current layout here ... />

    <TouchBlackHoleView
        android:id="@+id/black_hole"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

And then define your custom view with something like this:

```
public class TouchBlackHoleView extends View {
    private boolean touch_disabled=true;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return touch_disabled;
    }
    public disable_touch(boolean b) {
        touch_disabled=b;
    }
}
```

Then, in the activity, you can disable the touch with

```
(TouchBlackHoleView) black_hole = findViewById(R.id.black_hole);
black_hole.disable_touch(true);
```

And enable it back with

```
black_hole.disable_touch(false);
```

Comment: `View view = findViewById(R.id.whole_view);
 view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
  
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return true;
 }
});
`

i wrote this on start of my animation but it didn't work
kindly tell me where am wrong

Comment: here whole_view is the id of my main layout

Comment: What kind of view is it and what are you trying to disable ? Is it a button ? a ScrollView ? ... ?

Comment: i have buttons all over my layout. i wish to disable them

Comment: What kind of Layout do you have ? Maybe you could use a FrameLayout and overlay a View over it where you could enable / disable the touch down... let me write some pseudo code in the answer...

Comment: and outside that i wrote this

`public class TouchBlackHoleView extends View {
    
 public TouchBlackHoleView(Context context) {
  super(context);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 }
 private boolean touch_disabled=true;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return touch_disabled;
    }
    public void disable_touch(boolean b) {
        touch_disabled=b;
    }
}`

Comment: and using the **TouchBlackHoleView** am not able to put a background image
By the way, am using table layout inside the linear layout

Comment: Thanks for so much of help and as you said, i tried this. but its showing this error in the LOG .** Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.touch/com.example.touch.Disable_touchActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout**. and inside the oncreate function i have written

`setContentView(R.layout.main); TouchBlackHoleView view; view = (TouchBlackHoleView) findViewById(R.id.black_hole); ((TouchBlackHoleView) view).disable_touch(true);`

Comment: are you sure the view you defined with android:id="@+id/black_hole" is the TouchBlackHoleView? From the error, it looks like it is a LinearLayout...

Comment: yes sir its the id of linear layout.
actually am not using the touchblackholeview coz am not able to put a background image over there.

Comment: Glad you got it working... although I thought you did not want to use setClickable...?

Answer (score 2):

Easy way to  implement that is add transaperent layout over it (add it in your xml fill parent height and width).

In the animation start: `transaparentlayout.setClickable(true);`

In the animation end:  `transaparentlayout.setClickable(false);`

Answer (score 1):

answer to this issue

`for (int i = 1; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        TableRow row = (TableRow) layout.getChildAt(i);
        row.setClickable(false);`

**selected all the rows of the table layout which had all the views and disabled them**

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I took as a basic answer of @Matthieu and make it work such way. I decide to publish my answer because it take me maybe 30 min to understood why I got error.

XML

```
<...your path to this view and in the end --> .TouchBlackHoleView
    android:id="@+id/blackHole"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Class

public class TouchBlackHoleView extends View {
    private boolean touchDisable = false;

```
public TouchBlackHoleView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public TouchBlackHoleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public TouchBlackHoleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return touchDisable;
}

public void disableTouch(boolean value){
    touchDisable = value;
}
}
```

Using

```
blackHole = (TouchBlackHoleView) findViewById(R.id.blackHole);
blackHole.disableTouch(true);
```

Enjoy