# Single touch in ANDROID

Tags: android, android-canvas

Is it possible to allow the user to touch the screen only once?

Meaning: A user touches the screen and if he tries to touch the screen again nothing will happen. I am implementing the approach using `canvas` to draw the objects on the screen.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: try keeping a boolean flag

Comment: What are you doing on first touch? Drawing?

Comment: Declare one global boolean variable and use this as your requirement

Comment: @Naddy I am clicking on an element that i drew(lest say rectangle). It draws the new elements and after the drawing i want to prevent the user to click again.

Comment: Add a `boolean` flag as mentioned above. When the user clicks on your `rectangle` just change the `boolean` flag to `false`. Do the clicking part only when your flag is `true`.

Comment: we can help better if you show us what you have done.

Comment: I used boolean variable so some of the above mentioned comments to be converted into an answer so i can accept it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what you have in mind, setClickable() or onTouchEvent would be the best way to go.

Have a look on this reference:

- [Responding to Touch Events](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/touch.html)
- [Disable All Touch Screen Interactions While Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987633/disable-all-touch-screen-interactions-while-animation)
- [setEnabled() vs setClickable(), what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615823/setenabled-vs-setclickable-what-is-the-difference)

Comment: The thing is that i am using canvas for the drawing

Answer (score 0):

As commented above - use a boolean variable as a flag and toggle it between true and false according to how the user interacts!